# Problem with making else if statement work

Tags: c

**Can someone help with the else if statements. This is the script:**

**What I am trying to do is for example type ¨2¨ and make it calculate the subtraction of two numbers but it always starts with the first if statement before continuing through the entire script. So basically it's ignoring what I am typing at the start when I want to choose the type of calculation I am looking for.**

Comment: `if ("x == 1")`  This is covered in ***literally*** every textbook, example and online C programming guide.  Where did you get this from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've put the conditions into double quotes, those are then evaluated as true, that's why it always runs the code in the first if block. Change

```cpp
if ("x == 1") // always true
//...
else if ("x == 2")
//...
```

to

```cpp
if (x == 1) // true when x has the value 1
//...
else if (x == 2) // true when x has the value 2
//...
```